# Purge deleted source files from a WD My Passport backup

Tags: backup, external-hard-drive

Does anyone know how to purge deleted files (on the backup source) from a WD My Passport that also contains additional data using WD SmartWare?

I guess you can delete the files from the disk one by one on the backup, but thats not what I'm looking for as it would not be viable solution after deleting e.g. hundreds of images on the source.

**Edit**: As @Ramhound pointed out below, the easy solution is to use another solution than WD SmartWare. I'm however keeping the question up so that other with same problem can find this information, or WD SmartWare gets better.

Comment: Using WD SmartView. Looking for something similar to this feature: https://wdc.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/2708/~/how-to-remove-or-delete-files-from-a-backup-destination-using-wd-anywhere-backup

Answer (score 1):

[Edit] It seems not all files need to be deleted. Just ones missing from the source.

Deleted previous answer (which was use format to delete/purge all files)

```
Desktop:                          Backup folder on external drive:
                                  old_picture.png
file1.png                         file1.png
fill2.png                         file2.png  
file3.png
```

rsync with the `--delete` flag will:

- Copy the new files (efile3.png in this example)
- Check other files for changes (if file1.png or file2.png have been changes the newer version from the desktop will be copied. If unchanged no copy takes place)
- Due to the `--delete` flag the file old_picture.png will be deleted.

Comment: I asked for a way to purge the deleted files and not format the disk. I'm backing up a slow usb 2 machine and doing a re-backup of gigabites with image/video after a cleanup is not viable.

Comment: @grm - Why don't you just delete the files?

Comment: In that case, I do not get it. You made a backup to an external drive. That drive has your backup files (and I assume only that). You want to purge/delete all files from the drive. But not with format? Then what do you precisely want?

Comment: @Ramhound from the passport? Imagine editing hundred of images on your source then manually deleting the same files on the backup media? Hopeless!

Comment: @Hennes I don't want to purge all files. I only want to purge files that are DELETED from the source. Also, you can't assume the disk only contains backup files.

Comment: Ah. Now it makes sense.  Which OS? If unix like check out `rsync --delete`.

Comment: @grm - You could simply stop using the backup tool that Western Digital provides. The entire problem you have is because the tool doesn't give you an option to wipe data.  The "deleted" files if they take up space on the hdd can be deleted, I would just delete those files, follow the directions in the article you linked to.  Add the information the hdd contains other data thats important.

Comment: @Ramhound good point! I was hoping it was a way...

Comment: @Ramhound edited and keep it up so that other people can find this information. I will look for some better software. Thanks.